# How do I track the number of occurences in a string in python using a for or while loop?

Tags: python, string, loops

So I want to track the amount of times the substring "hi" has been used in the string "kjdhsfhiskdjhi" using a for loop.

so far, this is what I have. The problem is, that it only counts the number of letters in the string

```
s = "kjdhsfhiskdjhi"
substring = "hi"
numofhi = 0
for substring in s:
    numofhi += 
print('number of times hi occurs is: ' + str(numofhi))
```

Thank you!

Comment: `print("kjdhsfhiskdjhi".count("hi")) # 2`

Comment: Always check the official Python docs first, e.g for strings https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html or https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html. If the documentation there does not answer your question, only then ask it on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer that RomanPerekhrest gave is the most simple and effective.

If you really need a for loop, you could use:

```
s = "kjdhsfhiskdjhi"
substring = "hi"
substring_length = len(substring)
numofhi = 0

for chunk in ["".join(s[x:x+substring_length]) for x in range(0, len(s), substring_length)]:
    if chunk == substring:
        numofhi += 1

print('number of times hi occurs is: ' + str(numofhi))
```